# Forecasting surface visibility with (right-)censored data

Tags: regression, forecasting, nonlinear-regression, censoring

I have a bunch of surface visibility data measured at several ground weather stations over a certain period of time. The data for some of the stations are right-censored, e.g. a significant percentage of the total stations cap their max-visibility records to 10km, others to 16km, while others report values up to 80km. I should say I don't care much about forecast accuracy beyond 10km, as I am forced to threshold my forecast to 10km (as per the reporting requirements). What I *do* care very much about is forecasting rare *low-visibility events*.

I'm trying to build a simple predictive model for visibility that accounts for the data being censored. As predictors I have a bunch of other weather information recorded at the stations; those data are not censored.

**Question**: What model(s) are fit for purpose in this scenario? I'm looking at nonlinear models (neural-nets, etc.) as visibility is known to depend non-linearly on my predictors. How do I "tell" the model that its predictand was censored?

[Full disclosure: I've done a bit of reading on *Tobit models*. I'm unclear how I can inform these models that my visibility data come from several different measurement processes - essentially that different censoring thresholds were used, as explained above.]

Comment: A consideration of how best to express visibility might automatically solve your problem.  For instance, it's plausible that using the *reciprocal* of the visibility distance might be a more suitable way to express visibility, in which case numbers like ">10,000 m", ">80,000 m", etc, would all be in the range from 0.00001 to 0.0001 and thereby be effectively the same as zero and coding them as zeros might make no difference at all to your model, which is concerned with values with reciprocals exceeding 0.002, which is orders of magnitude greater.

Comment: good thought. I'll try this out and report back here.